# How the antenna on the B737 Max fuselage doesn't disrupt the airflow?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, boeing-737, boeing

As the title already say, how does the antenna on the Boeing 737 Max fuselage not disrupt the airflow?

[image]
([Boeing](http://www.boeing.com/resources/boeingdotcom/commercial/737max/assets/images/news/high-bandwidth-antenna-offers-enhanced-connectivity-in-the-air/gallery/gallery-large-01.jpg)) 737 MAX antenna.

Comment: Edited to make your question more understandable. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for some more details on how to post a good question on this site.

Comment: [Which antenna](http://www.boeing.com/resources/boeingdotcom/commercial/737ng/assets/images/marquee.jpg)? Are you talking about the satellite antenna that is added (not shown in that picture)?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! [Somewhat related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1603/62). A picture would be really useful here: aircraft have [lots of different antennae](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8779/62) and it isn't clear if you mean one specific antenna, or all of them together?

Answer (score 3):

*Anything* new attached to the outside of the airplane will change the airflow in someway; that is unavoidable.

The only question is if it will disrupt the airflow in a way that has a significant negative impact on the plane.

You'll recognize that the antenna is installed very close to the CG, so the new air resistance has virtually no pitching moment.

It is far from any control surface, so those all work the same.

The increased air resistance affects fuel economy a very tiny amount, but paying customers have enough preference for inflight wifi that its worth it.

Comment: Do you think it could be a safety issue?

Comment: What kind of safety issue?